# Exclude a returned representation in django restframework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a Serializer but I want to set a calculation whether to include it in serialized return objects or not.

```
class TradeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    .
    .
    .
    .
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        if ret['countdown'] < 5:
            # STOP! Do not return an object anymore!
            return
        return ret
```

But the syntax above will return something like `ret[None]`. I looking for an absolute exclusion

Answer (score 1):

You can made custom queryset to filter out your countdown < 5 before serializing the objects. You cant filter out objects in serializer, this is not the purpose of serializers, but you can raise validation errors if you want.

Comment: I see. If a raise a ValidationError I guess it still will not exclude but instead just raise an error

Comment: Yes, like I said all the filter happens in query , not in serializer. it just validates fields and formats data.